# Unity Shader Graph - Glow motion of an object with Shader Graph

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

I'm new to shaders and with the new Shader Graph from Unity I'm trying to experiment and archive some effects that I have in mind for my games.

I want to get something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTTGl.jpg

I want a glow effect to go arround my object. In my case it's a square neon light, so it's simple I think.

What I have so far, experimenting and unifying different tutorials, effects, etc.:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkCZI.jpg

This is the current Shader Graph, i know its a mess and maybe there are useless nodes, etc.:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxKoq.jpg

This is the tutorial I think it's the most accurate to what I need:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJUlGJS3QpY

Thanks in advance for any tip that help me find the correct path to archive the effect.

EDIT:
To make it clear, the real problem for me is the motion effect. I already setup the glow effect with post-processing and bloom. My problem is how to do the effect arround the object. In my case it's a neon tube, so it's easiest I think, as the effect can be on all the object but from the start of the tube to the end. As the tube is closed, it will start again from the begining almost at the same point. Hope it make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can use post processing to get the effect your after, specifically bloom and tone mapping effects.

With post processing applied you just need to increase the color into HDR levels in your shader.

Applying a blur outside of post processing is actually extremely expensive and isn't really recommended unless there is absolutely no other option.

Comment: Hi Zami. Thanks a lot for your answer.
My problem here is not exactly the glow effect but the motion of the effect arround the object. 
I already have the glow effect with post-processing and bloom, but it's the path of that glow arround the object, or the object itself, as in my case its a pipe or neon tube, what is causing me problems to do.
I'm going to update my question to make it clear.